# How can I use an array formula to return column headers where the cell value is 0 but NOT blank

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google sheet, I have an array of student results, with the score in marks for different objectives in some recent projects. Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yoX3t9wxj0B1YSYSBikVC7_DEgofFc-bwZoslSYQpjs/edit?usp=sharing

At the end of each row, I'm trying to create a list of the objectives where the student scored zero marks.

I have an array formula which does this by returning the column header wherever there is a 0 result, as follows:

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(B2:I2=0,$B$1:$I$1,"")))

However, not all students have been set every objective- therefore some cells are blank. And at present the formula can't distinguish between the blanks and the zeros.

Can anyone recommend a way to fix the formula so it only returns column headers for the zeros, but  ignores the blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this formula in cell L2:

`=BYROW(C2:J,LAMBDA(ax,IF(COUNTA(ax)=0,,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(FILTER(C1:J1,ax=0,ax<>""))))))`

-

[image]

Comment: Thanks- I just get a #Ref! error saying that the result can't be expanded due to overwriting data in L3

Comment: this formula(array style) auto covers the entire column (L2 and below). you can clear the cells of existing formulas from L3 to bottom

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. (I don't yet really understand how it works, but it works!)